# Jquery Mobile slider not rendering properly in a dynamatically created dialog page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement a JQuery Mobile slider in a dialog page.

The dialog is created when I clicked on a button. In the callback for this button, I intend to get some JSON data from the server and populate the dialog with the data. The code snippet is as follows:

```
$('.class-CheckOutList').live ("click", function (event)
{
    $.post("getItemDataForDataEntry.php", {"name":selectedItemID},
        function(data){             
            $.each(data, function(index,value){
                dialogHTML = '<input type="range" name="slider"';
                dialogHTML +=' id="slider-0" value="0" min="0" max="100">';
                $("#itemDataEntryFormContent").html(dialogHTML);                        
                });
            }
            ,"json");
});
```

The problem is that the slider is not rendered properly for the above codes. Sorry, I can't post a picture to show what I get cos I am new to this forum.

However, the following code seem to work OK:

```
$('.class-CheckOutList').live ("click", function (event)
{
                dialogHTML = '<input type="range" name="slider"';
                dialogHTML +=' id="slider-0" value="0" min="0" max="100">';
                $("#itemDataEntryFormContent").html(dialogHTML);                        
});
```

Anybody can help?

Thanks.

+++++++++++++++++++

Update --> I have managed to solve the problem but another similar problem happens after I apply the solution.

What I done -->
Previously, to activate the call back, I used something like this:

```
    <a href='#itemDataEntryDialog' data-rel='dialog' data-role='button'>Change</a>";
```

to create the dialog.

The solution I did was to change the above to:

```
    <a data-role='button'>Change</a>";
```

and make the code changes as:

```
$('.class-CheckOutList').live ("click", function (event)
{
    $.post("getItemDataForDataEntry.php", {"name":selectedItemID},
        function(data){             
            $.each(data, function(index,value){
                dialogHTML = '<input type="range" name="slider"';
                dialogHTML +=' id="slider-0" value="0" min="0" max="100">';
                });
                $("#itemDataEntryFormContent").html(dialogHTML);                        
                          $.mobile.changePage($('#itemDataEntryDialog'), {role: "dialog"} );
            }
            ,"json");
});
```

All these changes do cause the dialog to render properly.

However, when I click the button a second time, the dialog rendering fail again (like before).

So, I am kind of back to square one .......

Would appreciate if can get some help here. It is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have called $('#myInput').slider() to force jquerymobile to initialise your new control.

In your case I would add something like :

```
$('#itemDataEntryFormContent input[type="range"]').slider()
```

...just between the html() call and the changepage() call.

Another useful function for the slider control is to call $('#mycontrol').slider('update') if you updated the value via script.

hope this help someone :)